# Is it possible to do 301 redirects by country?

Tags: redirects, 301-redirect

We have a `.com` website but operate in the UK and the US, we want the `.com` to 301 to the `.co.uk` website but for people in the UK only and the `.com` to remain as it is.
Is this possible with 301 - if not whats the best way around this?

Answer (score 1):

#### Using .htaccess

You do this with a simple `.htaccess` rule by detecting the browsers [`Accept-Language` (read here)](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mozilla.com/Localization#Straight-up_Language_Negotiation).

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-language} ^en-GB [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://example.co.uk [L,R=301]
```

#### Using PHP

You can do this with a programming language to perform a lookup (I generally use a 3rd party open API) then send the 301 header if it falls within your criteria.

For example, using PHP we can do the following;

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=". $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET"
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  //There was an error with the curl request
  //Don't do anything...
} else {
  $res = json_decode($response, true);
  if( strtoupper($res->geoplugin_countryCode) == "GB" ) {
    //Issue the 301
    header("Location: http://example.co.uk", TRUE, 301);
    die;
  }  
}
```